# Use openpgm on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, network-protocols, multicastsocket, pgm-protocol

I've faced a problem using Openpgm library, and I would be grateful if anyone could help me on this problem.

I want to use Openpgm on Ubuntu 12.04. according to this link: "https://code.google.com/p/openpgm/wiki/OpenPgm5CReferenceBuildLibrary" Openpgm was tested on Ubuntu 8.04 to 10.10.

I downloaded latest version of Openpgm(5.2.122) and compiled it with "scons" without error. According to the link I should see a compiled example named "pgmrecv" and "pgmsend" in path "*./ref/debug/examples/" but there isn't such example, Instead there was "purinrecv" and "purinsend". I run receiver first like this : "./purinrecv -lp 3065" then sender like this : "./purinsend -lp 3065 please work" , there was no error message in both , but the receiver didn't receive anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems offtopic for SO, you should ask on [su] or [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: I think SO is best place to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what typically happens when the default interface on the host is not suitable for use with multicast.  This has been improved in the trunk code and the interface can be overridden with the `-n` parameter, e.g.

```
./purinrecv -l -n "eth0;239.192.0.1" -p 7500


./purinsend -l -n "eth0;239.192.0.1" -p 7500 please work
```

Replace `eth0` with something that has a network connection.